# Error trying to start mongodb

Tags: linux, mongodb, centos

I have a problem when try to start mongodb, below I show you the error:

```
    xxx@xxx [/var/lib/mongo]# /etc/init.d/mongod start
    Starting mongod: all output going to: /var/log/mongo/mongod.log
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Seeing on mongod.log I get the following notifications:

```
***** SERVER RESTARTED *****


Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.860 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=19148 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=srv1.canoa.net
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.860 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.0
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.860 [initandlisten] git version: ce2d666c04b4a80af58e8bbb3388b0680e8cfeb6
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.860 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.861 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.861 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongo", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongo/mongod.log", pidfilepath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.861 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.861 dbexit:
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.861 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.861 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.861 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.861 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.861 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.861 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.861 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.861 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.861 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.861 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.861 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Something that gets my attention is this:

`Thu Mar 21 12:10:20.861 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating`

The folder and files inside /var/lib/mongo has 0755 permission.

If anyone can tell me a way to do this, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Does /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock exist?

Comment: @user20140268 Yes, /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock exist

Answer (score 5):

I solved the error, it was because I only had `mongod` user assigned to the `/var/lib/mongo` but not the files within, the following command resolved this part: `chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongo`.

Then only had to repair the database with the user `mongod` with the following command: `sudo -u mongod mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --repair`, I finally started the database successfully.

I hope this will be helpful to other.

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the last time the `mongod` process was terminated incorrectly, try to remove `mongo.lock` this should help

Comment: if its an option, trying using different dbpath and check. 
   mongod --dbpath

Comment: @user20140268 This is the output : drwxr-xr-x 5 mongod mongod 4096 mar 21 12:59 /var/lib/mongo/

Comment: I know it's a little lame, but try to run the `mongod` with `sudo`. I have no other ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are running the *service mongodb start/stop/restart/status* commands as root ?? .. using sudo ? I get that error if I try to start it as a regular user.