# Cannot get Mongodb started on CentOS 6.4

Tags: mongodb

I installed the following 2 packages on my CentOS 6.4 machine:

1. `mongo-10gen-2.2.3`
2. `mongo-10gen-server-2.2.3`

I then rebooted my machine.

I ran the following command as root to see if Mongodb was up:  `/etc/init.d/mongod` status

It returned the following:  `mongod is stopped`

The following line from `var/log/mongo/mongod.log` concerns me:  `Thu Jun 13 13:25:15 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating`

Yet, when I run `/etc/init.d/mongod` status, it says `mongod is stopped`.
Also, when I run `ps -ef | grep mongo` it returns no results.

Does anyone know who I can get Mongodb running on my machine?

Thanks.

Comment: Your init.d script probably runs mongod under a MongoDB specific user. Can you check whether this user has permission to write to /var/lib/mongo?

Comment: Hi James...The ownership for /etc/init.d/mongod is root:root.  The ownership for /var/lib/mongo is mongod:mongod.  The ownership for /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock is root:root.  I believe that root would have permission to write to /var/lib/mongo.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi again James...It appears you were right about this being an ownership issue.  I found the following article:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552989/error-trying-to-start-mongodb.  I followed the first set of directions and ran chown -R mongod:monnod var/lib/mongo.  I then rebooted my machine (to make sure Mongodb came up after being rebooted).  When my machine came back up, I ran the following command as root:  /etc/init.d/mongod status.  The command replied that mongod is running...  I do have one follow-up question...

Comment: My follow-up question is:  If you go to the URL I gave, I followed the first part of the user's instructions but did not follow this part of the instructions:  "only had to repair the database with the user mongod with the following command: sudo -u mongod mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --repair, I finally started the database successfully".  I figured that I did not need to do this because when I run /etc/init.d/mongod status, it replies that mongod is running.  Does anyone think I do need to follow the second set of instructions?  Thanks again James for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You do not need to run --repair. This is only needed in cases where your data files may be corrupt. Doesn't sound like it applies in your case.

Comment: Hi James...thanks for confirming that I don't need to repair the database.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem using Fedora 19, and my /var/lib/mongo directory and files had the right permission, but mongod refused to start because of "Permission denied" on /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock

**The problem was actually SELinux**... I don't know the correct solution for this, but disabling SELinux at least let me run mongo.

```
# setenforce 0
# service mongod start
```

I know it's an old question, but I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

The mongod init.d script will likely launch `mongod` under a MongoDB specific user. Make sure this user has permission to write to `/var/lib/mongo`.